# 'onPress' not working in react-native on android

Tags: android, react-native, svg

I'm using a `<G>` component with an `onPress` handler

```
<G onPress={() => toggleRegion('ne')}>
...
</G>
```

The `toggleRegion()` handler fires every time on iOS (emulator, real device via expo-go, and real device via deployed app. It always fires in the android emulator but not consistently on a real android device either in expo-go or in a deployed app.

I'm experiencing the same issue with [this snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@msand/react-native-svg-example) which is part of the [react-native-svg documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this using `onPressIn` instead of `onPress`. No idea why the latter works but the former fails. Sure feels like a bug.

Comment: It seems like it's related to a bug in react-native-screens: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36710

Answer (score 2):

I had exact same issue with "react-native": "0.72.1" used onPressIn but it seems not a good practice when using scroll views. It is caused by the new architecture. fixed it by setting `newArchEnabled=false` in gradle.properties.

Comment: it's not a answer. you could comment it under the question

Comment: @MohammadBaqer Edited